# Split an array of non-negative values into as many groups as possible under the constraint that the sum of each group >= a given value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

For example, if we have an array [4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 3] and the minimum group sum is 5,

then the following grouping meets the requirement:

[1, 2, 4], [2, 3], [5]

I think it's the best we can do, i.e., we can't split the array into 4 or more groups without breaking the constraint.

The solution to this problem that I can think of is to first sort the array and then process the array from the largest value.

- If it is greater than equal to the minimum, then it constitutes a group already.
- If it is less than the minimum, enroll it into a temporary group first and then look at the other end of the sorted array. Starting from the smallest value that has not yet been grouped, we repeatedly add values into the group until the group sum is equal to or greater than the minimum.
- Repeat the above two steps until no more elements can be consumed, i.e., the sum of all the remaining elements is less than the minimum. As a final step, we add all these elements to any of the existing groups.

Take the previous array again as an example. We first sort it into [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5]:

1. 5 can be split into a separate group.
2. 4 is less than 5, so we add 1, the smallest ungrouped value to it and form a new group.
3. Similarly, group 3 and 2.
4. 2 is the only remaining element. We can put it into any of the existing groups.

I'm not quite sure whether this seemingly greedy approach works but I can't figure a counterexample off the top of my head. The uncertainty lies in the 3rd step. Is it possible that we can somehow extract one or more elements from existing groups and combine them with the remaining ungrouped values to create one more group?

I'd like to know if my solution is correct or any other solution that works (ideally in polynomial time).

Comment: What would your algorithm do for the array [2, 3, 4, 4, 5] and group sum = 9?

Comment: Nice example. It indeed doesn't work because it would end up with a 1-group partition.